# Is Reissner's Mixed Variational Theorem (RMVT) available in Abaqus?

Tags: abaqus

Is there a tool in Abaqus capable of implementing a Reissner's Mixed Variational Theorem (RMVT) or would I have to implement a subroutine for it?

I would like to have a system in which I have the in-plane displacements (x, y, and xy) and out-of-plane stresses as variables (tau xz, tau yz, and sigma z)